# UINavigationBar BarButtonItem with Plain Style

Tags: iphone, image, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

i got the following code:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      self.title = @"please wait";
      UIBarButtonItem *favorite = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonFavoriteClicked:)];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favorite;
  }

  return self;
}
```

but my button looks still like a Button with UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
[image]

is there a way to set a button with plain style at this position?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a UIButton in interface builder, make it look like exactly what you want. Create an outlet for in in your .h:

```
IBOutlet UIButton * _myButton;
```

Then set it as your right bar button item using a custom view, which will eliminate the border:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_myButton];
```

This works because UIButton is a subclass of UIView.

Comment: Also if you want to get drop shadow effect plain buttons have do this: `_myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;` `_myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;` `_myButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;` `_myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1 ? -1:-1.5);`

Comment: I agree with this solution. But, do you think apple does this in their iPad mail app? seems kinda a small hack.

Comment: @ajayjapan UI Guidelines say that navigation bar ignores item's `style` property because borderless buttons aren't appropriate for the navigation bar. As for Mail, there is a navigation bar on the left side (with bordered buttons) and there is a toolbar on the right side (which allows borderless buttons).

Answer (score 23):

Try this instead:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      self.title = @"please wait";

      UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
      [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonFavoriteClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      UIBarButtonItem *favorite = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
      [button release];

      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favorite;
  }

  return self;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should release `favorite` too, after assigning.

Answer (score 8):

Or do this in code without IB:

```
// add setting button to nav bar
UIImage* settingsGearImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_gear.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, settingsGearImg.size.width, settingsGearImg.size.height);
UIButton *settingsButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[settingsButton setBackgroundImage:settingsGearImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[settingsButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *settingButtonItem =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingsButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingButtonItem;
```

Results in:

[image]

When using this icon image (it's white on a white background so isn't visible here - link is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk5SB.png):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's weird but it works. Say "No" to images/outlets! You shouldn't even set the UIBarButtonItemStylePlain property. The trick is to place button into UIToolBar with some special attributes:

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cool plain bar"];
UIToolbar *tools = [[UIToolbar alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.01f)];
tools.clipsToBounds = NO;
tools.barStyle = -1; // clear background
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
UIBarButtonItem *bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshTableView)];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
UIBarButtonItem *rightButtons = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];

item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtons;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;
[myCoolNavigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Frank is right, this code should be in `viewDidLoad`, the issue here is what BarButtons look like. If you want it to look different, you need to use a different type of UIView. You can add a UIButton to a UIToolbar just fine.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"please wait";
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIButton alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Edit:

Sorry, you wanted a plain UIBarButtonItem. I don't believe you can do this with a UINavigationBar. You could try adding a UserInteractionEnabled UILabel as the rightBarButtonItem, I'm not sure if it will work or not.

**<strike>Seems this isn't currently possible.</strike>

[sbwoodside has a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2895137/447356).**

Comment: also, rightBarButtonItems need a UIBarButtonItem as Object Type

Comment: Really? Damn, I know you can stick whatever you want in the title. That's really disappointing.

Comment: `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem;` hm, or do i interpret something wrong?

Comment: Nope, you're definitely right, I just never noticed as I always use the bordered button.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try UI7Kit? Works well for me, easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"white_star.png"];

      CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(20, 20);
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
      CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
      [img drawInRect:imageRect];
      img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


  UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc ] initWithImage:img style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(favoriteButtonClicked)];
  barButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

Comment: The code contains errors and is not what he was looking for.  `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`is not a UIBarButtonItemStyle.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(didPressButton)];
```