# Create a UIBarButtonSystemItem with UIBarButtonItemStyle

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I want to create a system UIBarButton, but I want it to have plain style.
I've tried with this code, but the style is ignored. 
What's wrong with it?

```
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearch)];    
search.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = search;
[search release];
```

Comment: `search.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;` is unnecessary as `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` is the default value for the style property of this Class.  From [UIBarButtonItem_Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/UIBarButtonItem_Class.pdf).

Comment: I add it to try to remove the borders. Documentation says plain style is the default, but that's not true in my case. The system button is bordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348440/uinavigationbar-barbuttonitem-with-plain-style).

It seems that the way to go about making this plan is to create your custom UIButton and assign it to the bar button.

Comment: Using UIButton I lose the advantage of system button that is avoid to create my own image.

Comment: I understand. I can't verify this without trying this out on code, but I'm wondering whether that could be the issue here -> Perhaps the system buttons come with their own border style by default. Will look into it if I get some time.

Comment: I ended up creating an image. Not what I was looking for, but it seems the only solution.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this myself... Don't want to re-create the standard button images. Nothing yet...

Answer (score 2):

The main thing here is that you need to place your button in the previous controller, not in the one that is going to be pushed.

```
//Your actual ViewController
UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(showSearch)];    
search.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = search;
[search release];

//Controller that is going to be pushed and will display the new UIBarButtonItem
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```