# iOS: UIBarButtonItem won't turn plain style on storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to make a `UIBarButtonItem` on a `UINavigationBar` plain style on storyboard, but it won't change as you can see on the picture. On the other hand, I have no problem doing it on a toolbar. Why is this happening?

[image: screenshot from xcode]

Comment: Probably duplicate from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348440/uinavigationbar-barbuttonitem-with-plain-style

Comment: he was trying to make it plain programatically, I'm just wondering if there's a reason I can't do it through storyboard, since, apparently, that option's there.

Comment: Yes sorry, I know, but the problem is the same, UINavigationBar won't render a plain style, so you need a work around. The simplest one, is to create a UIButton with Custom style, and put it inside (or over) the Navigation bar. You can achieve this with IB also.